# Why is Connecting to a guest VM on a Hyper-V 2016 workgroup server failing?

Tags: windows, windows-10, remote-desktop, hyper-v, windows-server-2016

I'm a bit new to this and I'm likely missing something obvious.

Scenario:
Hyper-V 2016 (the free, headless one)
Windows 10 Pro

I've got Server Manager installed and the Hyper-V server is added successfully. I can connect my Hyper-V Manager to the Hyper-V server and I can create VMs, change settings etc. But when I go to actually create a guest VM, I cannot actually remote into the Guest VM. It fails with an error. The KB article only shows resolution steps for those working with Azure which I'm not AND the resolution is for the VM *But the VM hasnt had it's guest OS installed yet so I can't do this*.

For the record, I've got a user account on both sides with the same password incase it's something funky like that. I hate workgroups.

Here's the error that pops up when trying to open the guest VM:
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZh0K.png)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was because of the latest Windows 10 update. It was updated further then the 2016 ISO that is up to date.

Setting my windows 10 pro to vulnerable in the GPO corrected this issue